# Django & Mongoengine get data from embedded document?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I am having trouble retrieving data from the embedded document in mongoengine.

models.py

```
from mongoengine import Document, EmbeddedDocument, fields



class ProductFields(EmbeddedDocument):
    key_name    = fields.StringField(required=True)
    value   = fields.DynamicField(required=True)

class Product(Document):
    name        = fields.StringField(required=True)
    description = fields.StringField(required=True, null=True)
    fields      = fields.ListField(fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(ProductFields))
```

views.py

```
class ProductListView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        # list_products = Product.objects.all()
        result=[]
        productfields = ProductFields
        for product in Product.objects:
            data={
                "name":product.name,
                "description":product.description,
                # "key":product.fields.key_name,
                # "value":ProductFields.value,
            }
            print (data)
            # print(productfields.key_name)
            result.append(data)
        return Response({"products":result,"message":"list of products.","requestStatus":1},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Output:

```
{
        "description": "test description",
        "name": "product1"
        "fields":[ 
           { "key_name" : value},
           { "key_name" : value},
           ]
}
```

How do I get the above-desired output? Print function doesn't work because mongoengine returns object and not the value.

Answer (score 0):

Here I see you're using **APIView** from  [Django Rest FrameWork](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework). Have a look at [django-rest-framework-mongoengine](https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine). If you're already familiar with DRF, you can use [this](https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine) extension to create your API endpoints with MongoDB easily.

You must have found some workaround by now even though you can mark this answer as correct so that if anyone else runs into the same problem in future, they can get the solution.